# Storing multiple fields in lmdb for use with caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I'm building an lmdb database for a caffe net, which stores various images, like this:

```
txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(dbCtr),currImageDatum.SerializeToString())
```

Where I'm storing two strings as a key, value pair. However, I'd also like to store some meta-data. Specifically, I'd like to store the name of the file from which the image came. My understanding is the `value` must be a single string and not something like `[currImageDatum.SerializeToString(), 'myImage.jpg']`.

So, the only way I can think to do this would be:

```
txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(dbCtr),currImageDatum.SerializeToString() + '__MY_META_DATA__' + 'myImage.jpg')
```

and then, when reading the lmdb, to split the value string into the part before '__MY_META_DATA__' and the part after it.

Is this a reasonable approach? Is there some other standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the way caffe's `"Data"` layer reads `Datum` from lmdb is quite strict and you cannot easily change it.
If you are considering alternatives to lmdb, look into [`"HDF5Data"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/hdf5data.html) layer which is much more flexible.